# ngOnInit not firing when opening dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, electron

When opening the dialog, `ngOnInit` is not being called. The only way I can get it to fire is when I resize the window. I tried using `detectChanges` and `zone.run()` but it did not change anything.

Here is the code for the dialog component:

```
(settings-dialog.component.ts)

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from '../../providers/electron.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings-dialog',
  templateUrl: './settings-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class SettingsDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  public settings;

  constructor(
    private electronService: ElectronService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Getting settings');
    this.getSettings();
  }

  private getSettings() {
    this.settings = this.electronService.settings.getAll();
    console.log(this.settings);
  }
}
```

```
(settings-dialog.module.ts)
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { SettingsDialogComponent } from './settings-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  providers: [ ],
  declarations: [ SettingsDialogComponent ],
  entryComponents: [ SettingsDialogComponent ]
})
export class SettingsDialogModule { }
```

The component is being loaded from the menu bar setup with Electron:

```
(app.component.ts)

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { SettingsDialogComponent } from './dialogs/settings-dialog/settings-dialog.component';
import { ElectronService } from './providers/electron.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public electronService: ElectronService, public translate: TranslateService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.setupMenu();
  }

  private setupMenu() {
    const menu = this.electronService.remote.Menu.buildFromTemplate([{
      label: 'File',
      submenu: [{
        label: 'Settings',
        click: () => this.openSettingsDialog()
      }]
    }]);

    this.electronService.remote.Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
  }

  private openSettingsDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(SettingsDialogComponent);
  }
}
```

```
(app.module.ts)
import '../polyfills';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WorkspaceModule } from './components/workspace/workspace.module';
import { SettingsDialogModule } from './dialogs/settings-dialog/settings-dialog.module';
import { WebviewDirective } from './directives/webview.directive';
import { ElectronService } from './providers/electron.service';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WebviewDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    WorkspaceModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    SettingsDialogModule
  ],
  providers: [ElectronService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What am I missing? What have I done wrong? (I don't might trying stuff again)

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted should work fine. Do you mind creating a stackblitz for minimum reproduction ?

Comment: @SachinGupta It's an Electron project and the dialog is opened from the menu bar in the "File" dropdown. I've never used stackblitz but I don't think it supports Electron apps and won't be able to reproduce the application's menu bar. If you want, here is the repo URL: https://gitlab.com/thebird956/open-3d-asset-library

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> I tried using detectChanges and zone.run() but it did not change
>   anything

You were on the right way but maybe didn't use it properly. When you click on menu in electron app you leave ngZone. So the following code should work and ngOnInit should be trigger as I've checked:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
...
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(...private zone: NgZone) {}


  private openSettingsDialog() {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.dialog.open(SettingsDialogComponent);
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This answer saved my day! :) Cheers.

Comment: Works for Angular Elements as well.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: This issue seems to appear on regular web pages as well, any time a dialog is opened from the app component when the page is showing a different component. In my case it was a timeout dialog. Wrapping in a zone.run call fixed it.